# How to convert label in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, label, jupyter

Here is code to convert the label in Jupyter notebook:

```
ef conv_label(label):
    if label == 'Aadil Aadil':
        return 0
    elif label == 'Alvi Nastaleeq':
        return 1
    elif label == 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq':
        return 2
    elif label == 'Nafees Nastaliq':
        return 3
    elif label == 'Najd':
        return 4
```

Above code shows this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-e0f63475442c>", line 1
    ef conv_label(label):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: An aside for anyone looking to avoid writing nested if-else statements like this is that in Python a dictionary (see the bottom half of [here](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2019/06/05/pythonic-ways-to-use-dictionaries/)) or enum (see [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/03/20/python-3-an-intro-to-enumerations/) would probably be preferable to code and read.

Answer (score 2):

```
def conv_label(label):
    if label == 'Aadil Aadil':
        return 0
    elif label == 'Alvi Nastaleeq':
        return 1
    elif label == 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq':
        return 2
    elif label == 'Nafees Nastaliq':
        return 3
    elif label == 'Najd':
        return 4e here
```

You forgot the "d" for def at the beginning.